# Why am I getting error 1064 with my code? I Checked Stack Overflow but I can't pinpoint the error with the code

Tags: mysql

```
Create Table Items
(i_num Integer Not Null Primary Key,
i_title Varchar (50) Not Null,
d_num Integer Not Null,
i_price Decimal (6,2) Not Null,
i_release_date Date Not Null,
i_genre Varchar (15) Not Null Check
(i_genre IN ('Jazz', 'Blues', 'Country', 'Rock', 'Alternative', 'Rap', 'Classical', 'Other')),
Foreign Key (d_num) References Distributors (d_num),
On Update Cascade
On Delete Cascade);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is why am I getting the error on my code.

Comment: Please show the actual error message, not just the error number.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'On Update Cascade
 On Delete Cascade)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create Table Distributors (
  d_num Integer Not null
);

Create Table Items(
i_num Integer Not Null Primary Key, 
i_title Varchar(50) Not Null, 
d_num Integer Not Null, 
i_price Decimal(6,2) Not Null, 
i_release_date Date Not Null, 
i_genre Varchar(15) Not Null, 
constraint FOREIGN KEY (d_num) REFERENCES Distributors(d_num) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
Constraint ´genre_items_in´ Check (i_genre IN ('Jazz', 'Blues', 'Country', 'Rock', 'Alternative', 'Rap', 'Classical', 'Other'))
);
```

Try this, You were using unncessary "," symbol in your command while defining cascades.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
Constraint ´genre_items_in´ Check (i_genre IN ('Jazz', 'Blues', 'Country', '' at line 8

Comment: Create Tables Items
(i_num Integer Not Not Null Primary Key,
i_title Varchar (50) Not Null,
d_num Integer Not Not Null,
i_price Decimal (6,2) Not Null,
i_release_date Date Not Null,
i_genre Varchar (15) Not Null Check
(i_genre IN ('Jazz', 'Blues', 'Country', 'Rock', 'Alternative', 'Rap', 'Classical', 'Other')),
Foreign Key (d_num) References Distributors (d_num)
On Update Cascade
On Delete Cascade);

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Tables Items
(i_num Integer Not Not Null Primary Key,
i_title Varchar (50) Not' at line 1

Comment: Edited it and works in fiddle now. Problem with unnecessary closing braces ')' in line Foreign Key(d_num). and It works in sqlFiddle.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Distributorsd_num ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
Constraint ´' at line 8

Comment: Please copy paste the above code because the above provided code is working  on sqlFiddle.

Comment: Copied and pasted it but still get the above error message.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 5.